# Python: Why does removing frequencies using FFT approach not seem to have removed periodicity in data?

Tags: python

I have a time series of various meteorological data that all show a clear diurnal and seasonal cycle when visually inspected. I am attempting to remove these seasonal and diurnal cycles from the time series using a FFT approach. I have removed nans from the dataset via linear interpolation. Each variable is measured at uniform intervals of 1 minute and is stored in an array (y) that is 1012320x1 long (703 days worth of data)

So far I have the code:

```
#Calculate the anomalies from the mean of time series y
y = y - y.mean()

#Calculate FFT 
fftVar = np.fft.fft(y)

#n = 1012320
n = len(y)

#Just take positive values
n2 = np.divide(n,2)
rng = range(1,int(n2))

#Define sampling rate and normalization factor 
#1440 = number of minutes in a day (to get result in cycles/per day) 
Fs = np.divide(1,1440) 
norm = n*Fs

#Calculate frequency
frq = np.divide(rng,norm)

#Calculate power 
n3 = np.floor(n2
rng2 = range(1,int(n3))
pwr = np.abs(fftVar[rng2])**2 

#Remove frequencies not needed 
frqThreshold = 0.9 
for j in range(len(frq)):
    if frq[j] >= frqThreshold: 
        fftVar[j] = 0.0

        #Found this section online, not sure what this line does
        #When uncommented, I get bizzare result (see 3rd example below)
        #fftVar[int(n2) + j] = 0.0 

postFFT = np.fft.ifft(fftVar)
```

Plotting the power vs frequency gives the following (for one example variable):

[Before diurnal/seasonal cycles were removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L12Qz.png)

[After diurnal/seasonal cycles were removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kaljk.png)

So I am reasonably confident that this part worked (I am aware that this is a very crude method of doing this, at this stage that is acceptable). If I have done things correctly, the y-axis should be power and x-axis should be frequency, with peaks at 1 cycle/day for the diurnal cycle and then another peak showing a longer cycle.

The problem (I think) occurs in my treatment of the resulting time series after the frequencies have been removed. Below are the plots showing one variable (the same example variable as above) before and after I have removed the frequencies:

[Example time series of variable before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx70S.png)

[Same variable and time after the FFT analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbrAQ.png)

[Same variable and time after the FFT analysis, with specified line of code uncommented (see code block)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZQ30.png)

Note that the x-axis for both is time (1 day in length), and the y-axis for the before plot is raw values (Pa in this case) and should be anomalies from the mean with no diurnal/seasonal cycles in the second plot.

I am a beginner in signal processing, so I cannot even begin to understand what the 3rd plot is showing me, or if this is "more correct" or "less correct" than before.

I plotted the plot using the following simple code:

```
plt.plot(postFFT,'k-',linewidth=1.5)
```

However - the frequencies don't seem to have been removed. In the code, I figured that setting the results of fftVar to 0 whenever the frequency was above a certain threshold and then performing the inverse transform would do this - but I was wrong (or at least coded it up incorrectly).

I am a first time user of python, and there is doubtlessly many ways to improve the code above (I would be grateful for any pointers here as well, if anyone has time) but I am mostly intrigued as to why this code is not removing the frequencies required (or if it's maybe just a plotting problem)?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some problems to understand your code but I think the problem is that you didn't set the fourier transform at negative frequencies to zero as well. Here is some code with fabricated data, which includes seasonal, biseasonal and diurnal contributions from which the diurnal ones are filtered out.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()


t = np.linspace(0,10*365,1e5)

y = np.sin(2*np.pi*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*t/365) + np.sin(2*np.pi*t/365/2)
y = y - y.mean()

#Calculate FFT
freqs = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(len(y),t[1]-t[0]))
fftVar = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(y))

fft_filtered = fftVar.copy()
# set spectrum above frequency treshold to zero. It is important to also set the negative frequencies to zero, 
# which probably caused your problem
fft_filtered[np.abs(freqs)>1e-1] = 0 


postFFT = np.fft.ifft(np.fft.ifftshift(fft_filtered))
plt.figure(1,figsize=(9,7))
ax = plt.subplot(211)

ax.plot(t,y)
ax.plot(t,postFFT)
ax.set_xlim(t.min(),t.max())
ax.set_xlabel('Time [days]')

ax1 = plt.subplot(212)
ax1.loglog(freqs,np.abs(fftVar)**2)
ax1.plot(freqs,np.abs(fft_filtered)**2)
ax1.set_xlim(1e-3,freqs.max())
ax1.set_ylim(1e-6,1e10)
ax1.set_xlabel('Frequency [1/days]')
```

The result is the following figure, which shows the filtered and unfiltered time series and spectrum. The thick blue blob is the diurnal oscillation, which is unresolved in the plot because the timespan is so large (10 years).
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me figure out what was going on - code works now!

Answer (score 1):

Your data is being acquired at 1 minute interval, so Fs = 1/60 not 1/1440.

It is not clear to me what is exactly not working for you, but try this modified version.

```
from scipy.fftpack import fftfreq

# Sampling rate
Fs = 1.0/60.0

#Calculate the anomalies from the mean of time series y
y = y - y.mean()

#Calculate FFT 
fftVar = np.fft.fft(y)

#calculate the frequencies.
#Here 1/Fs is the sampling interval, which is 1 minute (60 seconds)
f = fftfreq(len(y), 1/Fs)

#Remove frequencies not needed 
frqThreshold = 0.9 * Fs/2

fftVar[(f >= frqThreshold) | (f <= -frqThreshold)] = 0.0

postFFT = np.real(np.fft.ifft(fftVar))
```

Also, to do digital filtering, you might want to consider using `butter` and `filtfilt` from `scipy.signal`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, both of the answers here made me realize that I was doing something very silly and I wasn't interpreting the results like I should have been.

It was very helpful to know I had Fs incorrect and that I had not accounted for the negative frequencies. I accepted the other answer purely because I ended up learning a few more things about Python from going through their code line by line, but yours worked too. Thanks!